# how to change date format in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date, sql-insert

The default date format in my SQL is : '`2019-05-06`'
and its fine but when i insert date to my table i want this format `2019-5-6` not the above format

It means month and day must be start 1 to 30 not 01 to 31.Is there any way to change default format in my sql?

Comment: `INSERT INTO t(i,d) VALUES(1, '2019-5-6')` **[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=28a0df070df751785e25f61b74c030bf)**

Comment: i use a library to convert timestamp to persian date and after the convert i have this 1397/5/6 and when insert to table it becomes this 1397/05/06

Comment: Where does come from your `date_time` format. Is it come from or get data from your system?

Comment: @sajadsholi not sure why you want to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for [the MySQL `STR_TO_DATE` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) :

> It takes a string `str` and a format string `format`. `STR_TO_DATE()` returns a `DATETIME` value if the format string contains both date and time parts, or a `DATE` or `TIME` value if the string contains only date or time parts.

So if the date coming out of your application is like `'2019-5-6'`, to convert it to a MySQL date you need :

```
STR_TO_DATE('2019-5-6', '%Y-%c-%e')
```

In an `INSERT` statement :

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(1, STR_TO_DATE('2019-5-6', '%Y-%c-%e'));
```

Tip :

- `%Y` : Year as a numeric, 4-digit value
- `%c` : numeric month name (0 to 12)
- `%e`: day of the month as a numeric value (0 to 31)

Answer (score 0):

The default way to store a date in a MySQL database is by using DATE. The proper format of a DATE is: YYYY-MM-DD. If you try to enter a date in a format other than the Year-Month-Day format, it might work but it won't be storing the dates as you expect.

In order to run a MySQL Insert command and add the current date into your table you can use MySQL's built-in function CURDATE() in your query.

An example of how to Insert a Date in MySQL using CURDATE

```
$query_auto = "INSERT INTO tablename (col_name, col_date) VALUE ('DATE: Auto CURDATE()', CURDATE() )";
```

Also, you can run a query to set the date manually

An example of how to Insert a Date in MySQL manually

```
$query_manual = "INSERT INTO tablename (col_name, col_date) VALUES ('DATE: Manual Date', '2008-7-04')";
```

It is recommended to do the date formatting when doing a query, like so:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(BirthDate, "%W %M %e %Y") FROM Employees;
```

You can find more examples of formatting the date here:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp